# How to find out if a directory is a valid PostgreSQL cluster

Tags: postgresql

I have some code which calls the pg_ctl command on a given path and checks the output to determine whether it is a valid PostgreSQL cluster:
`pg_ctl status -D <data_directory>`

However, while unittesting a negative on a known non-cluster directory, it isn't reliably returning the expected result of `pg_ctl: directory <data_directory> is not a database cluster directory` on my build server; instead it returns `pg_ctl: no server running`.

Is there a more fool-proof way of determining if the directory is a valid cluster?

Comment: It's simple to determine it *isn't*. Missing `PG_VERSION` file, `global/pg_control`, etc. Determining it *is* valid is open ended; what defines "valid" and how strict do you want to be? If you're just looking for "looks reasonably like a PostgreSQL data directory", check for `PG_VERSION` and the presence of `base/pg_control`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the following commands to initialize the DB directory.

```
$ initdb -D <data_directory>
```

Then you can get the information about initialization.

By the way, if you want to start your psql quickly, set PGDATA variable in configuration file, then use `pg_ctl start` to start your psql.

Comment: `-bash: initdb: command not found` - running on debian, what's the alternative ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/initdb`

Answer (score 1):

To start first time your Postgres server with single node. We should following steps,

Step 1. Create directory let say: /home/rajeev/pg_data_1

Step 2. initialize the cluster that copy all exe, lib, dependency config etc.
  postgres_home> initdb -D /home/rajeev/pg_data_1

if successfull initialize your server you will get following log message

***Success. You can now start the database server using:
    pg_ctl -D ^"/home/rajeev/pg_data_1" -l logfile start***

Step 3: Start Postgres node 
$postgres_home>pg_ctl.exe -D /home/rajeev/pg_data_1 start -U postgres -P pass123 -S auto

Step 4: start postgress CLI

> psql -U postgres